# Sass mixins to output variable in comments

Tags: sass

When working on a big sass library, I like to include flags; big flags for files that import and small flags for the imported files.  This makes debugging in the browser easier because I can quickly find the associated sass files and make the change.

Is there a way to have a mixin output comments with an assigned variable?  Here's what I've tried.

```
@mixin bigflag($filepath){
      /***********
        ******  $filepath
       ***********/
    }

@include bigflag(scss/middle/header.scss);
```

I'd like the above code to output as

```
      /***********
        ******  scss/middle/header.scss
       ***********/
```

This did not work; the non closing comment makes the variable inactive, or commented out.  I guess I could be copying and pasting the comment flags, but...  This would be very convenient.

Any help is appreciated.  Thank you

Comment: Sass already provides debugging options, why don't you use them?

Comment: Less aptly described as debugging, perhaps my need is better described as pixel perfection.  Rather than try a value in sass, save, recompile and check the browser, I can toggle the value from within the browser dev tools, find the exact value I want then change the sass file.  These flags allow me to quickly figure out which file I need to change once I'm done toggling in the inspector.

Comment: And?  The `--debug-info` flag adds line numbers to show where the styles originate from.

Comment: workflow I suppose; I rely heavily on chrome dev tools for styling.  I'll experiment with the --debug-info and let you know how I make out.  Thank you for your attention to this issue.

Answer (score 1):

After some research on escape characters in sass

```
@mixin flag($file){
/***********
******  #{$file}
***********/
}
@include flag(scss/middle/header);
```

outputs as

```
/***********
******  scss/middle/header
***********/
```

one note:  sass doesn't like periods. so if you use flag(scss/middle/header.scss) you'll need to escape the period before scss.  This is painstaking and I'm not going to use it.

Comment: You should really just keep the comment headers in respective files.

Comment: Yes I am.  Defining the mixin is on the top level before the imports.  Each import includes the mixin at the top of the file.  So the compiled file has flags that indicate the top of each sass file.

Comment: Update:  Source mapping and workspace folders on dev tools renders this unnecessary.